# WSO2 Identity Server - REST APIs for permission and roles

Tags: rest, permissions, wso2, roles

I am using WSO2 Identity Server 5.7.0 and WSO2 API Manager 2.6.0. We want to use the user management and role & permissions management of WSO2 itself, but the as per requirement we cannot use WSO2 carbon management GUI for user creattion, role mapping etc.

We need to have a separate GUI but integrate with WSO2 User, Role and Permission management.

For this purpose, WSO2 must have some kind of APIs exposed for third party application integration?
For example, I have checked user creation, user update etc operations are having corresponding SCIM REST APIs which can be used by our applications.

Is there similar APIs for :

1) Creating Service providers
2) Creating permissions at service provider level
3) Creating role mapping at service provider level
4) Creating roles
5) Associating permissions with roles
6) Associating Users with Roles.

Please let me know details of such REST APIs provided by WSO2 if any.